# How to Remove a Column Article for Transaction Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replication

I followed the direction from the following link, [How to: Define and Modify a Column Filter (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146925%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  I currently have a setup where I'm replicating at table, Users.  We no longer want to replicate the column, SSN.  For my test, I inserted a new row into the Users table including the SSN.  I executed the following SQL statements with no errors.  After I synced the publication using the Replication Monitor, the new row didn't show up in my replicated database.  I decided to do another insert and resync.  The other row didn't show up the new one did with the missing SSN as I expected.  Is there something I did wrong?

```
exec  sp_articlecolumn       @publication = N'Publisher Test 01', @article = N'Users', @column = N'SSN', @operation = N'drop', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1, @force_reinit_subscription = 1
exec  sp_articleview         @publication = N'Publisher Test 01', @article = N'Users', @change_active = 1
exec  sp_startpublication_snapshot @publication = 'Publisher Test 01'
exec  sp_reinitsubscription  @publication = N'Publisher Test 01', @article = N'Users',  @subscriber = N'TEST', @destination_db = N'Test01_Replication'
```